# Animating linear css background not working in firefox

Tags: css, css-animations

I know this has been answered somewhere already, but can't figure out what's wrong. 
I have used repeating-linear-gradient for background and @-webkit-keyframes and @keyframes for animating it. It does work in google chrome but not in firefox.

HTML

```
<div class="menu_block"></div>
```

CSS

```
.menu_block {
  height:100px; width:500px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,#000,#000 20px,#fff 20px,#fff 40px);
  background-size:56px 56px; 
  background-position-x:0%;
  -webkit-animation:'slide' 30s infinite linear forwards;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes 'slide' {
    0%{background-position-x:0%;}
    100% {  background-position-x:100%;}
}
@keyframes 'slide' {
0%{ background-position-x:0%;   }
100% {  background-position-x:100%;}
}
```

jsfiddle is here

https://jsfiddle.net/mathews8881/0cj3L6wu/

Could somebody please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try animating both params `background-position: 0% 0;`. Also missing non-prefixed `animation` rule.

```css
.menu_block {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #000, #000 20px, #fff 20px, #fff 40px);
  background-size: 56px 56px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  -webkit-animation: slide 30s infinite linear forwards;
  animation: slide 30s infinite linear forwards;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_block">

</div>
```

Comment: @Mathew If my answer satisfies you, please accept it. Don't leave solved questions without accepted answer

Comment: I am also getting the same issue in this link. Can you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013326/slide-image-from-right-to-left-not-working-in-chrome-and-safari

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes on the `animation`/`keyframes` property values, the `-webkit-` prefix on `animation` and use `background-position: 0%;` instead of `background-position-x:0%;` (as mentioned in a comment, `background-position-x` is not supported across browser).

*Note, since your prefixed properties weren't consistent applied I removed all of them, so you need to add them back to cover older browser versions needing them. Also, in your case, no need to use `forwards` in your animation when using `infinite`*

```css
.menu_block {
  height:100px; width:500px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,#000,#000 20px,#fff 20px,#fff 40px);
  background-size:56px 56px; 
  background-position:0%;
  animation: slide 30s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0%{ background-position:0%; }
  100% { background-position:100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_block">   
</div>
```

Comment: both @justinas and yours worked. Thanks for your support guys.